# Как получить значение из textfield во Flet?

Tags: python, app, flet

> по задумке, должна быть кнопка, которая складывает числа из TextField

```
import flet as ft
    
    def main(page):
    
        first_name = ft.TextField(label="First name", autofocus=True)
        last_name = ft.TextField(label="Last name")
        greetings = ft.Column()
    
    ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: А что написано в документации? https://flet.dev/docs/controls/textfield/

Comment: `textfield.value`

Answer (score 0):

Для получения "label":

`first_name.label`

Получить "измененный label":

`first_name.value`

Пример программы:

```
import flet as ft

data = {"first_name": "first_name", "last_name": "last_name"}

def start_page(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Регистрация"
    page.window_width = 400
    page.window_height = 600
    page.window_resizable = True
    page.update()

    
    first_name = ft.TextField(label="Имя (необязательное поле)", autofocus=True)
    last_name = ft.TextField(label="Фамилия (необязательное поле)")
    greetings = ft.Column()

    def btn_click(e):
        greetings.controls.append(ft.Text(f"Hello, {first_name.value} {last_name.value}!"))
        data["first_name"] = first_name.value
        data["last_name"] = last_name.value

        first_name.value = ""
        last_name.value = ""
        page.update()
        first_name.focus()

    page.add(
        first_name,
        last_name,
        ft.ElevatedButton("Начать", on_click=btn_click),
        greetings,
    )
    
ft.app(target=start_page)

print(data)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]